# PHP regex look around with matching multiple occurrences

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the text that looks like this:

```
const {
    b {
        description "Create B1"
        uri "ms:///a/v1/create-b"
    }
    c {
        description "Create C1"
        uri "ms:///a/v1/create-c"
    }
    d {
        description "Create D1"
        uri "ms:///a/v1/create-d"
    }
}

const {
    b {
        description "Create B2"
        uri "ms:///a/v1/create-b"
    }
    c {
        description "Create C2"
        uri "ms:///a/v1/create-c"
    }
    d {
        description "Create D2"
        uri "ms:///a/v1/create-d"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get everything between `const` and this is what I came up with so far: `const {(?s)(.*)}.*?(?=const)`. That gives me just the first occurrence, and I can't figure out how to get all the other ones (in the original file there are more `const` objects).

Any push in the right direction would be welcome

The link where you can test this is here: https://regex101.com/r/I4W5cR/1

Comment: What language are you using? If you use Python `re.findall` or PHP `preg_match_all()` it should return all the occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may leverage the fact that each match starts with `const` at the start of a line:

```
(?sm)^const {(.*?)}\s*\R(?=const|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hv3WQ3/1)

**Details**

- `(?sm)` - `s` enables the DOTALL mode and `m` makes `^` match line start positions
- `^` - line start
- `const {`  - a substring
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `}` - a `}` char
- `\s*\R` - zero or more whitespaces and then a line break
- `(?=const|\Z)` - immediately on the right, there must be `const` or end of string.